# Code doesn't proceed beyond input stage

Tags: c++

I've constructed a simple program that is supposed to take an amount in cents that the user inputs and outputs it in the form of dollars and cents, however, when I run it, it asks me for the amount, I input it, and the program doesn't proceed. I'm new to programming and would dearly appreciate any help I can get on the matter

```
 #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int numb;
        int dollars=0;
        int cents=0;

        cout << "Enter the amount" << endl;
        cin >> numb;

        while (numb>=0);
        {
          dollars=int(numb/100);
          cents=numb%100;
        }

        cout << dollars << "dollars" << cents << "cents"<<endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: :Why are using while loop here?

Comment: try to use debugger and find error your self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop with your 'while' block, because numb is always positive (it doesn't change for any iteration).
Try removing the while loop to let the program proceed.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numb;
    int dollars=0;
    int cents=0;

    cout << "Enter the amount" << endl;
    cin >> numb;

    dollars=int(numb/100);
    cents=numb%100;

    cout << dollars << "dollars" << cents << "cents" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You can also have a look at other answers that give you ways to use a loop to repeatedly ask for (valid) user inputs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the while loop is there to handle invalid inputs (i.e. negative values), so it's not really a good idea to tell him to remove it without at least telling him the reason why. Also, this code does not handle non-numeric digits either.

Comment: Indeed, I should explain why. I have edited my answer in that direction. As far as the question goes, the OP is trying to let the program proceed; I think your answer is a good follow up for his simple program though.

Answer (score 2):

The code below should work as you expected.
Read the comments I inserted into your code for more information.
Also, you may want to insert extra check in the loop for invalid input (i.e. non-digit characters) as that will cause the loop to enter an infinite loop.

EDIT: I've updated the code with the extra check to handle invalid non-numeric user input.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numb = 0;
    int dollars=0;
    int cents=0;

    cout << "Enter the amount" << endl;

    // I suspect your while loop here is to keep soliciting input
    // if the input is not valid, so I've moved the "cin" into the loop.
    // Don't use semi colon here after the while statement because
    // in doing so, you're eliminating the body of the loop.
    while (numb <= 0)
    {
        cin >> numb;
        if(cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Non numeric input, please try again." << endl;
            continue;
        }
        cout << "numb: " << numb << endl;
        dollars=int(numb/100);
        cents=numb%100;
    }

    // I've inserted extra spaces around dollars and cents here
    // to make the output more readable.   
    cout << dollars << " dollars " << cents << " cents"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This while loop doesn't make any sense. Remove it.

```
while (numb>=0);  // remove this line and the '{' '}'
{
  dollars=int(numb/100);
  cents=numb%100;
}
```

Generally when using loops check that they will terminate. You are checking every iteration that `numb>=0` but inside the loop `numb` never changes it's value. So the program executes this loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

you made an infinite loop

```
while (numb>=0);
        {
          dollars=int(numb/100);
          cents=numb%100;
        }
```

numb is let's say 3, so this always 3>=0 equals true therefore, you neverexit that loop

Comment: You made crazy indentation. How come?